# How can a managed metadata field be associated with a term set with powershell?

Tags: powershell, term-set, managed-metadata-service

I need to associate the column to a term set using PowerShell.

Library name: Financial

Managed metadata column: Doc Type

MMS name: Managed Metadata Service Application

Group name: Project Management

Term set name: Project Taxonomy (v1.0)

Parent term: Financial

Term to be associated to the column: Doc Type

Answer (score 2):

Try it as below:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$WebURL="https://sitecollectionurl/"
$ListName="Financial"
$FieldName="Doc Type"

$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$List = $Web.Lists[$ListName]

if(!($List.Fields.ContainsField($FieldName)))
{

 $TaxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $web.Site
 $TermStore = $TaxonomySession.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"]
 $TermGroup = $TermStore.Groups["Project Management"]
 $TermSet = $TermGroup.TermSets["Project Taxonomy (v1.0)"]  

 $TaxonomyField = $List.Fields.CreateNewField("TaxonomyFieldType", $TermSet.Name)
 $TaxonomyField.SspId = $TermSet.TermStore.Id
 $TaxonomyField.TermSetId = $TermSet.Id

 #Add the field to List
 $List.Fields.Add($TaxonomyField)
 $List.Update()

 Write-host "Managed metadata column Added successfully!"-f Green
}
else
{
 Write-host "Managed metadata column with the specified name already exists!"
}
```